# Plot function with integral: find the right formula

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, graphing-functions, simple-functions

How can I plot a function like this?

[image]

Where $N_\mathrm{A,0}$ is constant. For now, let's leave out the details: I just want to know what equation I should write as the argument of the `\addplot` command in $\LaTeX$ TiKz pgfplots.

My attempt: solve the integral

$$ t = N_\mathrm{A,0} \int_0^{X_\mathrm{A,f}} \dfrac{d X_\mathrm{A}}{r_\mathrm{A} V} $$

$$ t = N_\mathrm{A,0} \dfrac{1}{r_\mathrm{A} V} X_\mathrm{A,f}$$

make explicit with respect to $\dfrac{1}{r_\mathrm{A} V}$

$$\dfrac{1}{r_\mathrm{A} V} = \dfrac{t}{N_\mathrm{A,0}} \dfrac{1}{X_\mathrm{A,f}}$$

this formula can be traced back to the form $y = 1 / x$, and as we know this formula returns the branch of a hyperbola, which is not what I want to get

Any idea?

Comment: Your first equation is not an integral. It's not clear at all what your inputs are

Comment: I think the problem is that you are treating $X_A$ as a constant with respect to $V$ when you integrate.  Should not the reaction rate, $r_A$ be a function of the concentration, $X_A$?

Comment: Please verify symbols: $V$ is volume, $r_A$ is rate of reaction, $t$ is time, and $X_A$ is concentration (for example, grams per liter or moles per liter).

Comment: @Doug $X_\mathrm{A}$ is the A convertion ( (initial A moles - A moles at equlibrium)/initial A moles) ) 
$0 \leq X_\mathrm{A} \leq 1$

Comment: Ahh, yes.  Since $N_{A0}$ already gives you units of moles...  Anyway, does my comment make sense, that the rate changes based on conversion?

Comment: @Doug yes! rate decrease as conversion increases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce a plot like the one you have attached:

**Experimentally**:
Do an experiment where you have fixed solution volume, $V$.  Measure concentration of $A$ at fixed times $t_i$.  If you know what should be equilibrium concentration of $A$, then you can calculate percent converion at each of these times.  Next, numerically differentiate the data at each time $t_i$.  Now, you have two plots:  Conversion vs time and rate vs time.  Since the times are the same between both data sets, take each rate value $r_a(t_i)$ and compute $1/(r_a(t_i)V)$.  Find the conversion at the corresponding time $X_A(t_i)$.  Plot the point $(1/(r_a(t_i)V),X_A(t_i))$ for each time $t_i$.  This should give you the desired plot.

**Mathematically**:
As to the nature of the curve in the plot, I would like to suggest that it is a rational function of conversion.  For example, conversion could take the form
$$X_A(t) \sim 1-e^{-t},$$
and reaction rate could take the form
$$r_A(t) \sim e^{-t}.$$

Now, note that
$$\frac{1}{r_A} \sim e^t = e^t(1-e^{-t})+1 = e^tX_A+1 = \frac{-1}{X_A-1}X_A+1 = 1+\frac{X_A}{1-X_A}.$$

So, I would say, use the general form
$$y = \frac{ax}{1-x}+1$$
for your plot, and tweak $a$ so that it looks as flat near $0$ as you wish.

[image]